# Problem converting cell link from Excel sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a workbook created with **Excel** .xlsx (Windows PC) that contains two sheets, S1 and S2.

In S1 there are single cells that are linked to single cells in S2 by using the cell name definition. These cell name definitions are created in S2 and reachable from the whole workbook (max scope).

So, in **Excel**, I click on a cell in S! to see the corresponding cell in S2. And viceversa. That's working fine.

Now, I put the file .xlsx into the **Google Drive** so I can reach it from the mobile or from another PC.

With the mobile, I use the Google's app **Sheets**. From PC I open the workbook using a specific extension of Google Chrome, installed in the browser.  Both, mobile and PC, opens the worksheet and I can see the two sheets in it; when I tap (with mobile) or click (using PC) in the cell with link, nothing happens; the link to the another cell doesn't work.

Seems a problem due to the conversion from **Excel** to **Google Sheet**. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: what do you mean by "With the mobile"?

Comment: @WeSee: With mobile I mean using smartphone, such as iPhone with iOS.

Comment: @player0 : Using Excel, the sheets works fine, so I suppose that the cell is referring rightly. The problem occur after conversion. Is it possible that Google Sheets doesn't support the cell link as defined in Excel?

Comment: Have you tried Excel Online? Why do you you want to convert an Excel file to Google Sheets? Will you need to convert the spreadsheet back to Google Sheets?

Comment: @rubén : I also tried with the Excel app for iOS but I get a result similar to Google Sheets. With Excel, the link seems work fine but in the cell in S1 I read the defined name in sheet S2 instead its value. Example: In S1 the cell contains the value "40". In S2 the linked cell is named "Cell40" and contains the value "40". So, In S1 I read "Cell40" instead of "40".

Answer (score 0):

While both apps are spreadsheet applications and several features works the same way on both, other several features are exclusive of one or the other application. i.e. Google Sheets has IMPORTRANGE built-in function but Excel doesn't.

AFAIK [Open Document](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) scope is only about how data is saved in order to make it able of being opened by supporting applications but there isn't a standard for the way that applications works.